# Why does my SQL query differ when displayed in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

When I execute SQL into phpmyadmin, it gives the correct results (as you can see the two order_id's at the first column of the table are different):

[image: First column]

However, when I call the SQL into PHP, it displays differently, displaying two rows of order ID #99:

[image: Two rows]

This is the SQL:

```sql
SELECT o.order_id,o.farm_id,o.user_id,o.created,u.first_name,u.surname,u.email, 
       u.telephone_no,ua.user_id,ua.street,ua.town,ua.county,ua.postcode,bc.* 
FROM   orders o 
       LEFT JOIN users_address ua 
              ON ua.user_id = o.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN users u 
              ON ua.user_id = u.id 
       LEFT JOIN basket_checkout bc 
              ON ua.user_id = bc.user_id 
WHERE  o.farm_id = 10 
   AND bc.farm_id = o.farm_id 
GROUP  BY o.order_id 
ORDER  BY bc.order_id ASC
```

This is how I call the SQL into PHP:

```
<?php $query = "<the query>";
$data_set = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connection'], $query);
confirm_query2($data_set, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data_set)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <!-- Order ID -->
            <td class='orders-table' style='font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;'>
                <?php echo "<span><a href='{$view_order}.php?id=" . $row['order_id'] . "'>#" . $row['order_id'] . "</a></span>"; ?>
            </td>
            <!-- Name -->
            <td class='orders-table'>
                <?php echo "<span>" . $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['surname'] . "</span>"; ?>
            </td>
            <!-- Email -->
            <td class='orders-table' style='word-wrap:break-word;'>
                <?php echo "<span>" . $row['email'] . "</span>"; ?>
            </td>       
            <!-- Telephone no. -->
            <td class='orders-table' style='width:0px;'>
                <?php $telephone_no = substr_replace($row['telephone_no'], '-<br />', 4, 0); ?>
                <?php echo "<span>0" . str_replace("+44", "", $telephone_no) . "</span>"; ?>
            </td>
            <!-- Street -->
            <td class='orders-table' style='text-align:left;'>
                <?php echo "<span>" . $row['street'] . ",</span>"; ?><br />
                <?php echo "<span>" . $row['town'] . ",</span>"; ?><br />
                <?php echo "<span>" . $row['county'] . ",</span>"; ?><br />
                <?php echo "<span>" . $row['postcode'] . "</span>"; ?>
            </td>               
            <!-- Total -->
            <td class='orders-table'>
                <?php echo "<span>" . "£" . sprintf("%0.2f", $row['produce_total']) . "</a></span>"; ?>
            </td>           
            <!-- Items -->
            <td class='orders-table' style='width:0px;'>
                <?php echo "<span>" . $row['total_items'] . "</a></span>"; ?>
            </td>               
            <!-- Order created -->
            <td class='orders-table'>
                <?php echo "<span>"; if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['created'])) == date('Y-m-d')) { echo "Today<br />" . date('(H:i)', strtotime($row['created'])); } else { echo date('d/m/y (H:i)', strtotime($row['created'])); } echo "</span>"; ?>
            </td>
            <!-- Processed -->
            <?php if ($btn) { ?>
            <td class='orders-table' style='width:0px;'>
                <input type="submit" name="submit<?php echo $row['order_id']; ?>" value='Process' onclick="return confirm('Do you want to process this order?');" style='margin-left:1px;font-weight:bold;color:green;' />
            </td>       
            <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You should really show the `<insert the table as rows>` code, since that's what generates the output that you're saying is wrong.  It also might help to show the definition of the `confirm_query2()` function.

Comment: Okay, I will do that

Comment: Not sure if it is leading to your problem without digging into it further, but you're using `GROUP BY` incorrectly here.  MySQL lets you get away with it, but _technically_ every SELECT-ed column should either be aggregated (SUM, COUNT, etc) or listed in the GROUP BY clause.  Not doing so can lead to unexpected results.  Also, do you have an `order_id` column in any tables besides `orders`?

Comment: Yes, 'basket_checkout' also has 'order_id'

Comment: Okay, that's going to be a problem then.  You're selecting the same column name twice.  So is `$row['order_id']` supposed to know which to use?  Personally, I strongly advise against using `*` in `SELECT` lists.  Instead, get in the habit of selecting only those columns which you actually need, and alias them when necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I shorted the code. What I actually use is this: SELECT o.order_id, o.farm_id, o.user_id, o.created, u.first_name, u.surname, u.email, u.telephone_no, ua.user_id, ua.street, ua.town, ua.county, ua.postcode, bc.*

Comment: Even there, you're still using `bc.*`, which is going to include the repeated column.  Also please, please only ever post your _exact_ code.  Posting anything else wastes your time and ours.

Comment: Ah yes, that was it, the bc.*. Thank you for your help and advice

Comment: You're welcome.  Do take heed of my note about `GROUP BY` usage and [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html), specifically the paragraph starting with "MySQL extends the standard SQL"